# Writing modular pages with ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, web-architecture

I'm developing ASP.NET MVC 4 application, that will be used to configure a complex application. I want to have **one** configuration page, with multiple tabs. Each tab will be used to configure a different part in the system, and when you click on it the right form (each configuration tab will be a different partial view) will be loaded with AJAX. I want to have "Save Changes" button in the bottom of the page, that will save the changes from the whole tabs.

Since the system itself is modular, I want to make the configuration site modular too. Which means, that i want each tab to be some kind of a plugin that expose to me the following methods (by inheriting from an interface): GetConfigurationPartialView (which will return the partial view with the view model for this tab), SaveChanges (which will save the configuration to the DB as a draft), and GetConfigurationXml which will export the full XML configuration and apply it on the system.

My questions are:

1. What do you think about that design? do you have better ideas?
2. How do you recommend to implement this one "Save Changes" button in the main view? How can I iterate all of my plugins and call each plugin's SaveChanges method, pass it the correct model object (which is the partial view's model) filled with all the data without having intimate knowledge of each plugin object in the main controller/view so i can keep this system easy to extend?
3. Some of the tabs includes grids with data. i started looking into Kendo UI grid. I want to let the user do everything on the grid, in the client (deleting and add new rows), and then i want in the SaveChanges method i wrote about to get list in the server side of all the changes that the client did (for example, in pseudo code: changes[0]={Action = Delete, ProductID = 1}, changes[1]={Action=New, ProductID=1, Name="aaa" }). How can i do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the 'KISS' acronym is apt - Keep it Simple Stupid. Don't over engineer, sounds like this would be difficult to maintain

Comment: If it turns out this only complicate stuff, i'll probably make it more simple. i'm trying to check if i can do a bit more work now to save a lot of time in the future (and make it easier to maintain), since new kinds on configurations are added to this system regulary, and i want to make it really easy to add them to the configuration site too.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a partial view for each configuration page and load it as needed. I concur KISS is best.